# deleting a row in mysql and android - relational databases

Tags: php, android, mysql

In android app the user can insert a player's name, his rating and post that data in my server. This is done by the following working code.

```
<?php
 session_start();
 require "init.php";
 header('Content-type: application/json');

 error_reporting(E_ALL); 
 ini_set("display_errors", 1);

 $id_isSet = isset($_POST['player_id']);
 $user_id_isSet = isset($_POST['User_Id']);
 $best_player_isSet = isset($_POST['player']);
 $rate_isSet = isset($_POST['rating']);

 if($id_isSet && $user_id_isSet && $best_player_isSet && $rate_isSet){

$id = $_POST["player_id"];
$user_id = $_POST['User_Id'];
$best_player = $_POST['player'];
$rate = $_POST['rating'];

$sql_query = "INSERT INTO rating_players_table VALUES('$id','$best_player','$rate','$user_id');";

if(mysqli_query($con,$sql_query)){

                $don = array('result' =>'success','message'=>'Προστέθηκε');
                //$don = array('result' =>"success","message"=>"$id");

   }       
 }else if(!$best_player_isSet){

    $don = array('result' =>"fail","message"=>"Insert player name");

}else if(!$rate_isSet){

    $don = array('result' =>"fail","message"=>"Rate player");

  }
  echo json_encode($don);

?>
```

Now I want the user to delete the players he rated. So for that I am doing the following.

```
<?php
  include("init.php");


  $delete_post = "delete from rating_players_table where    
  id='$_GET['player_id']'";

  $run_delete = mysqli_query($con,$delete_post);

  echo json_encode($don);

   }
 ?>
```

Do you see what I am doing in the deleting code? I use the `$_GET['player_id']` is order to delete the corresponding row. However, this code doesn't work. Any ideas on this problem? I am suspecting that the `$_GET['player_id']` returns nothing, even if the `rating_players_table` has some rows of data.

Finally this is my android code.

```
 public void deleteRatedPlayer() {
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            URL.DELETE_RATED_PLAYER,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    Log.d("TAG", response.toString());

                    try {

                        if (response.getString("result").equals("success")) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else if (response.getString("result").equals("fail")) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
}
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    return (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK ? true :    
    super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event));
}
}
```

Comment: get some sql injection protection going. Also, user apparently doesn't need to authenticate to call and clobber (or insert)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, to fix your problem fix the deletion line:

```
// you cannot include $_GET['player_id'] directly in your string
// between the double quotes, you need to use concatenation in this case
$delete_post = "delete from rating_players_table where id='" . $_GET['player_id'] . "'";
```

Although this should solve the syntax problem, you still have another one: you don't check the input. I suggest you read about prepared statements in mysqli, about `filter_input` and SQL injection. Each one of the topics can be easily found with simple search.

```
// filter_input example usage
$player_id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'player_id', FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$delete_post = "delete from rating_players_table where id='$player_id'";
```

Also, I suggest you add some kind of an authorization to limit users' ability to remove another users' entries. Currently, if a player sends a request, you delete the row directly, but what if the user sends you another one's id?

Comment: The user registers and obtains his own id. So there is no problem with that.

Comment: You mean to use something like if (!filter_input(INPUT_GET, "product_id", FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS)) {...}

Comment: I added an example of filter_input to the answer

Comment: That's cool. In order to make it work I also need to do another thing. Pass the product_id into my android code. I should get it from the insert code shown in the question.